# I cannot log into workbench

Tags: workbench, login-errors

When logging into workbench I receive:

> An error has occurred and you have been logged out:
>   unknown_error: retry your request

Comment: Hi and welcome to all new SFSE users. If you found this question via search and are also affected, please do not add a "me too" answer. You're welcome to comment if you have information to add, or write an answer if you can help solve the problem.

Comment: Ticket about the issue posted on the forceworkbench GitHub site here: https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/821

Answer (score 4):

There is no trust site that I can find for workbench, but poking around the workbench menus turned up a help page that gives you a "report issue" link that takes you to a [github issues page](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues).

There is a specific issue for this occurance, https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/820 so I'd say that it's not just you.

The "answer" part of this answer is that there's not really anything you can do besides tracking the issue(s) on github (and that the source of information for workbench is github).

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Derek F's answer:

Since Derek posted the link, a user has posted a [solution](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/issues/820#issuecomment-519762240) on that page:

1. Login into the org.
2. Open up the Setup menu and navigate to Apps > Connected Apps > Connected Apps OAuth Usage.
3. Look for Workbench in the list.
4. Click on the number in the User Count column, which will open a new page.
5. On that page, look for the "Revoke All" button and click it.

This solution worked for me.